# Docker on CentOS report "unable to mount sys as readonly" when run

Tags: centos, docker

I'm just starting to use Docker, and trying to install Docker on a CentOS 6.5 (in VMware Player 6) according to [this official document](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/). All things went will until I try to start a container.

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t centos /bin/bash
2014/06/19 10:16:36 unable to remount sys readonly: unable to mount sys as readonly max retries reached
```

Additional information is listed below.

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.0.0
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.2
Git commit (client): 63fe64c/1.0.0
Server version: 1.0.0
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.2
Git commit (server): 63fe64c/1.0.0

$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
centos              latest              0c752394b855        9 days ago          124.1 MB
```

Could you please help figure out what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: VMWare got lot of products, which one is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably the issue is with native execution driver. Try to switch to lxc

edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file and make sure `other_args` contains `--exec-driver=lxc`

Example:

> other_args="--exec-driver=lxc"

And don't forget to restart the docker service...

Comment: Also seen on `RHEL 6.5`